# how to return back to previous activity on back pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity

i have call `Activity A` with state 2 from `Activity A` with state 1 then again call `Activity A` with state 3 from `Activity A` with state 2. Now how can i go back to `Activity A` with state 2 when i press on back button in android?

Comment: you can override `onBackPress` and do anything

Comment: on `onBackPress` finish the current activity as:  `this.finish();`

Comment: I think you have your activities mixed up,don't you mean Activity B somewhere there?

Comment: Call finish() method from Activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using following code-

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
startActivity(i);
finish();
}
```

Comment: By using this way you can start new activity and previous all activities on stack finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onBackPressed` for that.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ActivityB.this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    Intent intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```

You must Declare i to Intent, It's work for me ( API 23+ )